# Which strings does L language produce?

Tags: formal-languages

Let $L = 1 \cup (01 \cup 10)(00 \cup 11)^*0$. Which are the strings $L$ produces? I thought the ones that have even number of zeroes and odd number of $1$. But, you can not produce $111$. Then I thought that $0101010$ (four $0$s and three $1$s) can not be produced. Any ideas? I am struggling to find the answer!

Comment: As suggested in the answer by **vondbrand**, sometimes the simplest description of a language really looks pretty much like the expression you started with. There are some properties that can be deduced about the words in the language (such as the necessary, but not sufficient, condition of number of zeroes being even and number of ones being odd) which can be used to rule out some non-words quickly, but the full description of the language might just amount to translating the expression to human language.

Comment: So, nothing better can be said about it. :/

Answer (score 0):

First, the customary notation for union in regular expressions is a vertical bar, not $\cup$.

Next, a regular expression denotes a language, it doesn't produce one (the same way an algebraic expression describes operations that give a value).

Take the expression apart. First, it is the union of 1 and $(01\mid10)(00\mid11)^*0$.
Now analyze the later: It starts 01 or 10, then repeats pairs of 0 or 1, and ends in 0.

Comment: Well, I didn't write the exercise. :)

As for the terminology, ok, I didn't know that.

What you are presenting as an answer, is nothing more than what I can see. I am looking for something elegant, like the rule I tried to find before, but I didn't succeeded in.

Comment: @vonbrand Actually, the expression given does *not* look like it was supposed to be a regular expression -- it's a perfectly valid definition of language (= set of words) using set operations of union, concatenation and reflexive-transitive closure.

Comment: @user2411320 there is not always an elegant description of a language.

Comment: ok thanks. :) I am newbie.